# C# < cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'string'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I have trying to find a work around for this error, cause I am comparing the file size from the host to the one on the local system, but as I try this:

`if (CheckFileBytes < FileBytes)` it gives the following error

`Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long' and 'string'`

Here is some of the code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\checkfiles.lst"))
        {
            string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\checkfiles.lst";

            // Open the file to read from.
            foreach (string readText in File.ReadLines(path))
            {
                var elements = readText.Split('|');
                ElementsFile = elements[0];
                MD5Hash = elements[1];
                FileBytes = elements[2];
                //Console.WriteLine(ElementsFile + MD5Hash + FileBytes);
                string fileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + ElementsFile;
                byte[] buffer;
                int bytesRead;
                long size;
                long totalBytesRead = 0;

                using (Stream file = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                {
                    size = file.Length;
                    //var fileName = Application.StartupPath + "\\" + ElementsFile;
                    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                    var Filebytes = fi.Length;
                    using (HashAlgorithm hasher = MD5.Create())
                    {
                        do
                        {
                            buffer = new byte[4096];

                            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

                            hasher.TransformBlock(buffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);

                        }
                        while (bytesRead != 0);

                        hasher.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);

                        HashString = MakeHashString(hasher.Hash);
                    }
                    //Return Local file size
                    long CheckFileBytes = Filebytes;
                    //Return local MD5 hash string
                    string CheckFileHash = HashString;
                    //Return local file path
                    if (CheckFileHash != MD5Hash && CheckFileBytes < FileBytes)
                    {
                     ...
 }
}
```

the following were declared at the beginning of the class:

```
string ElementsFile = null;
string MD5Hash = null;
string FileBytes = null;
string HashString = null;
```

Comment: So, *what* exactly is unclear? You have a *number* (`long`) and a *string* and there is no defined ordering (or `<` operator) between them. I suspect that you'll want to *convert* the string to a number first .. or maybe not, but the cause of the error is the same.

Comment: `FileBytes` is a string by declaration.. We cannot compare long with string.. what your compiler says is right.. :)

Comment: I understand that, but how would I change them around to work?

Comment: How can you declare Filebytes as a string at the beginning of class and then do ... var Filebytes = fi.Length; This should not compile.

Comment: @IlyaNemtsev they are spelled differently, `FileBytes` and `Filebytes`

Comment: Convert FileBytes to a long.  e.g. long.TryParse(FileBytes, out i)

Comment: @Hulu8004 Do you mean to use `Filebytes` in the comparison instead? Anyway, the names are confusing. Fix them for clarity if for nothing else.

Comment: Should really work on the naming, variables usually start with small caps, otherwise difficult to read. If you want to compare a number in a string to a number use long.Parse(stringName); this will convert a string to a number long type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `FileBytes` as a long instead:

```
long FileBytes = 0;
```

Then convert your value from the file to a long when you assign it:

```
FileBytes = long.Parse(elements[2]);
```

Comparing to `CheckFileBytes` should work fine after that.

---

If there's a chance that `elements[2]` may not be a valid number, consider using [`long.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2x2b1h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

```
long.TryParse(elements[2], out FileBytes);
```

Comment: Where would I put `long.TryParse()`? would I do `FileBytes = long.TryParse(elements[2]);` or would I apply it else where?

Comment: When I applied that, it gave a conversion error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'long'`